# Trying to install android Parse, coming across many errors

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have been trying to install android parse using their empty project, however when I insert this line, it doesn't work:

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(myContext)
      .applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
.server("http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER:1337/parse")
```

The `MyContext` is in red, and shows the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'MyContext'`.

Also, I have just been made aware that android parse is no longer accepting sign ups, does that mean I won't be able to get the android parse server? Thus making my whole project based on it impossible?

Comment: I would suggest not using parse. this is going to out of service in future.

Comment: Why are you using Parse? It will retire on Jan 28, 2016. See http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: But I have Parse.Configuration cannot be resolved to a type please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: @BhavinkumarPatel did you solve it ?

Comment: yes, just put                Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
      .applicationId("APP_ID")
      .clientKey("CLIENT_KEY")
      .server("http://serverip:1337/parse/")
      .build()
  );

Answer (score 0):

Parse gonna expires on 28.1.2016.
try Mycontext change into ur classname like

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(Example.class)
```

Comment: It does? Argh, im trying to make an app for stock control that will allow for information to be inputted and then retrieved back through the application, is there other ways this can be done? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this) 
.applicationId("APP_ID") 
.clientKey("CLIENT_KEY") 
.server("serverip:1337/parse/") 
.build() );
```

And make sure parse server running
For this look at

http://julienrenaux.fr/2016/01/29/complete-parse-server-migration-guide/